# Can I hijack SMTP traffic on my local network?

Tags: smtp, wifi

A little background:

I'm getting married in June and want to setup an LCD TV at the reception so people can Bluetooth and email photos they take with their phone and have them display in rotation on the TV - I have no problem coding this.

However, after a visit to the venue yesterday I discovered that their wifi signal doesn't stretch to the room we'll be in.  I'm considering buying a wifi range extender, but wondered if I took my own wifi router, could I somehow hijack the smtp traffic from people's phones?  I could then take the photos straight from the email.

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Anthony Burns

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to set up a machine to display images it downloads and refreshes from a machine out on the web, then code a website that the guests could reach from their phones that will allow them to upload photos there.  They upload them, the server saves them, your display machine retrieves updates regularly and displays the whole batch at the party.

As for the bluetooth part, you might need to code something whole-cloth to allow them to temporarily pair with your display machine, upload photos there, have them send to your server on the internet (for safe-keeping) and then mix them in with your master photo file your displaying.

As for actually doing any of this...  I have no specific ideas - but it IS possible, just a LOT of coding, or some pretty impressive technologies.

Comment: Not sure you read the question properly - I don't have access to the web, the wifi doesn't reach the room we'll be in.  I can code all of the Bluetooth and email code, but want to know if there's a way I can hijack any SMTP traffic on a local network, so I could setup my own wifi router in the room.  Website idea is also no good, as you can't upload to a website from an iPhone, which is what most people will have.

Comment: You'd be better served by the Wi-Fi extender idea, in my opinion.  Hijacking any traffic can be rather dangerous (legally), and a serious breach of privacy - you'd have to sift through ALL of the SMTP traffic to find what your looking for, and if one of your guests is working on something sensitive, you've just made yourself party to it, even if only temporarily.  If your using iPhones, you might be forced to write an application those people use, and you'd have to get the developer's license to release it, etc.  At least, that's how I understand it.  Sorry I wasn't any help, in any case.

Answer (score 0):

I think making a website that allows image uploads with another page that displays all images would be pretty simple, just have the lcd hooked up to a laptop with the image viewing page displayed full screen and have it poll every few minutes for new images